# xsl unwanted next element - read attributes from tag and sub tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I got really close this time ;)

Bellow there is :

1. my xsl script
2. my xml file (that calls the script)
3. the output of the manipulation of the xsl on the xml (as shuold be)

My problem is that while the href and src value should be the same there is always one 
picture diff between them(pic3 and pic4) as though I'm calling the next pic element... yet I dont understand where I do that?

```
 <xsl:for-each select="data/pics/pic">
        <div>                   
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <img>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@src" />
                    </xsl:attribute>

                </img>
            </a>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

And this is my xml

```
<data>
    <pics>
        <pic href="pics\pic05.jpg" src="pics\pic05.jpg"></pic>
        <pic href="pics\pic04.jpg" src="pics\pic04.jpg"></pic>
        <pic href="pics\pic03.jpg" src="pics\pic03.jpg"></pic>
        <pic href="pics\pic02.jpg" src="pics\pic02.jpg"></pic>
        <pic href="pics\pic01.jpg" src="pics\pic01.jpg"></pic> 
    </pics> 
</data>
```

this should be the output:

```
<div>
    <a href="pics\pic01.jpg">
        <img src="pics\pic01.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="pics\pic02.jpg">
        <img src="pics\pic02.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="pics\pic03.jpg">
        <img src="pics\pic03.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="pics\pic04.jpg">
        <img src="pics\pic04.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="pics\pic05.jpg">
        <img src="pics\pic05.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me. I've enclosed your for-each in a <xsl:template match="/">. Using xsltproc (--version Using libxml 20706, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815) it produces the expected results, in reverse order (from pic5 down to pic1, same order as the source xml). Try creating a minimal, but complete (valid!) xsl template showing your problem.

Comment: ditto what rincewind said. Also post the actual XML output you are getting from your XSL stylesheet.

Comment: see my answer that reports that the provided transformation actually produces the wanted result.

Comment: +1 @ rincewind : First I'm glad I had this bug since I learned about the fact that I can check the xslt result using xsltproc ... or in my case I found eclipea very easy to use: http://www.vogella.de/articles/XSLT/article.html   .... Anyhow, the bug disappeared... must have been a cache issue. Thanks alot Asaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe XSLT processor you are using may have a bug, or you haven't provided the real xslt code and xml document.

**The provided XSLT code fragment when included in a complete stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
     <xsl:for-each select="data/pics/pic">
            <div>
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <img>
                        <xsl:attribute name="src">
                           <xsl:value-of select="@src" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </img>
                </a>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<data>
    <pics>
        <pic href="pics\pic05.jpg" src="pics\pic05.jpg"></pic>
        <pic href="pics\pic04.jpg" src="pics\pic04.jpg"></pic>
        <pic href="pics\pic03.jpg" src="pics\pic03.jpg"></pic>
        <pic href="pics\pic02.jpg" src="pics\pic02.jpg"></pic>
        <pic href="pics\pic01.jpg" src="pics\pic01.jpg"></pic>
    </pics>
</data>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html>
    <div>
        <a href="pics\pic05.jpg">
            <img src="pics\pic05.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="pics\pic04.jpg">
            <img src="pics\pic04.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="pics\pic03.jpg">
            <img src="pics\pic03.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="pics\pic02.jpg">
            <img src="pics\pic02.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="pics\pic01.jpg">
            <img src="pics\pic01.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</html>
```

**This transformation produced the same result when performed with several different XSLT processors**, such as MSXML3,4,6, Saxon6.5 and AltovaXML (XML-SPY).

**Do note**, that the transformation can be refactored into a much shorter and readable one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
     <xsl:for-each select="data/pics/pic">
            <div>
                <a href="{@href}">
                    <img src="{@src}"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```